# How to handle Platform Event while UI is being rerendered?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, platform-event, cometd

**Use case:**

We have Digital Experience (i.e Community) where at first we perform the `action` and after it, we redirect to a new page.

This `action` also publishes Platform Event (Notification) which should be handled on UI. The issue is that this Event comes to the UI while new `subscriber` is not yet registered.

**Question:**

So how do you handle a Platform Event during rendering and show information from it?

**Tried:**

I tried using session storage to store info and then display it once the new page is loaded, but it does seem clunky.

**My other ideas:**

Maybe someone had similar problem and solved it via storing the last processed event id or something like that?